# How to apply a fiter with substring on the property of AD Object without variable use?

Tags: powershell, shell, active-directory

I am working on getting a list of ad objects with particular values in their AD Properties but using a variable to store the value & then do a substring doesn't look like a convenient option to me. I did go through the documentation on Microsoft but didn't find anything substantial.

This is what I am trying to do for example:

```
Get-ADObject -filter { <propertyName>.Substring(8,4) -ne "S-XX" }
```

Is there a way to get the list of objects that contains a specific substrings in the values of the properties?

Answer (score 1):

[LDAP syntax for AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax) does not have substring, neither `any one symbol` placeholder.
This means, you can not make server-side substring-like filter when exact number of symbols are skipped. You can only use `*`, which means `value is defined and asterisk is 0 or more symbols`.

So, only way to get values you want is make query filtered by some way (or not filtered), and filter them again client-side with more complex rules.